# Parallel vectors to surface

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

> Find the surface integral of $\mathbf{u}\cdot\mathbf{n}$ over $S$ where $S$ is the part of the surface $z=x+y^2$ with $z<0$ and $x>-1$, $\mathbf{u}$ is the vector field $(2y+x,\,-1,\,0)$ and $\mathbf{n}$ has negative $z$-component.

I have the surface written parametrically as
$$(x,\,y,\,x+y^2).$$
In my book the authors claim two parallel vectors to this surface are $$(1,\,0,\,1)\quad\text{and}\quad(0,\,1,\,2y).$$
Since they don't show how this was achieved, I'm assuming there is some quick trick they used to find them. Anyone have a guess what that trick might be?

Comment: What do you mean "parallel vectors"? Do you mean a vector that is tangent to the surface? If so, you need so specify more than the direction of the vector, but also where the base point of the vector is.

Comment: @WillieWong I would assume tangent at every point. I'll update the question so it contains all the information. Also spotted a mistake, it should be $(x, y, x+y^2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your surface is the graph of the function 
$$ f(x,y) = x + y^2 $$
Therefore for any vector $v = v_x \partial_x + v_y \partial_y$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, based at the point $(x,y)$, you have a tangent vector to the graph given by 
$$ (v_x, v_y, v\cdot\nabla f) $$
based at $(x,y,f(x,y))$.

Now evaluate the above using first $v = \partial_x$ gives

$$ (v_x, v_y, v\cdot\nabla f) = (1,0,\partial_x f) = (1,0,1) $$

independent of $(x,y)$, the base point. Evaluating using $v = \partial_y$ gives

$$ (v_x, v_y, v\cdot\nabla f) = (0,1,\partial_y f) = (0,1,2y) $$

at the base point $(x,y)$.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how you arrive at the vector $v = v_x \partial_ x + v_y \partial_ y$? And how do you choose what $v$ to evaluate? Did you simply choose $(v_x, v_y) = (1,0); (0,1)$ because that is the most convenient?

Comment: You are parametrizing your surface using $\mathbb{R}^2$ since it is expressed as a graph. So $v_x \partial_x + v_y\partial_y$ is the general form of a tangent vector on $\mathbb{R}^2$. The choice $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$ is for convenience.